# javascript: surprising order of operations

Tags: javascript

I recently wrote code that didnt work as i would expect, it was:

```
message = 'Thank You';
type = 'success';

message = message || type == 'success' ? 'Success' : 'Error';
```

It was news to me that at the end of that `message` was set to **'Success'**.

I would think that since the truthy value of message is `true`, the right side of the `or` would **not** evaluate.

Parenthesis around the right side of the OR solved this, but i still dont understand why the right *side was evaluated at all*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to

```
message = ( message || type == 'success' ) ? 'Success' : 'Error';
```

That's why. :)

Comment: Yep, `?:` has the lowest priority... https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 3):

The value of `message` doesn't end up as `"success"` but `"Success"`.

The `?` operator has lower precedence than the `||` operator, so the code is evaluated as:

```
message = (message || type == 'success') ? 'Success' : 'Error';
```

The result of `message || type == 'success'` will be `"Thank You"`, and when that is evaluated as a boolean for the `?` operator, the result is `true`.